# Is there a way to write to a sharepoint excel file in real time from VBA without downloading the file and saving over the original?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am having difficulty finding a way to modify an online SharePoint file using excel VBA. The goal of the project is to create a live dashboard of all our company's trackers, which pulls in all the data from the trackers and consolidates them into one place for review, with the important feature that if a task is marked complete on the dashboard, the corresponding data on the original tracker is marked as complete as well. However, from what I've run into so far the SharePoint file size limit isn't enough for all the data I'm trying to pull in to just run this all from there. Therefore I'm making the dashboard in an offline format. This is where I'm running into my issue. I can open the files from SP via VBA and copy in the data but they are read-only and I haven't found a way to edit them without saving them as a new file and overwriting the old one Sharepoint. This solution isn't feasible as the SharePoint files are constantly being updated and this could overwrite data that wasn't there when I downloaded it. Looking for a way to update a SharePoint file dynamically and in real time from the offline file using VBA if this action is even possible.

Comment: It looks like you want to collaborate the file with others, no overwriting it. If you are on office 365, you can use `ThisWorkbook.AutoSave=True`. Otherwise, i don't think what you want is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

"I can open the files from SP via VBA and copy in the data but they are read-only" - you can definitely open a Sharepoint file read-write in Excel as long as you have the required privileges. Maybe you're using the wrong-format link?

The Sharepoint "Copy Link" doesn't typically give you what you'd need for this - see example below:

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook

'Direct from "copy Link" - doesn't work
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/DeptName/TestLibrary/Tester.xlsx?d=w6e00e447050d4e68b363c8a9311a5a99&csf=1&web=1&e=luXOna")

'works with some edits
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/DeptName/TestLibrary/Tester.xlsx")

wb.Sheets(1).Range("a3").Value = "Test"
wb.Close True  'save changes
```

See this thread for what those various "flags" in the URL are for:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/what-is-f-r-in-shared-urls/m-p/234117

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten but it doesn't quite work but thank you regardless for the help, it opens the SharePoint link offline and I can edit it, however, to save the changes I have to overwrite the original saved SharePoint file which I don't want to do. I'm looking more for a live modification same as if I had pressed "open in desktop" on SharePoint.

Comment: When I ran that code I also had the Excel file "Tester.xlsx" open in the Office online Excel web application: as the downloaded file saved and closed I saw the content update in the web view.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your workflow - I was assuming you were opening for editing and then immediately closing the file, without making a local copy.